# Merge 2 transparent PNG images with PHP GD library

Tags: php, image, image-processing, png, transparency

I am trying to combine two transparent *PNG* images. The second *PNG* image should have 50% opacity.

**The issue:**

If the second *PNG* covers only the non-transparent pixels of the first *PNG*, then everything is fine.

If the second *PNG* has areas which cover the transparent pixels of the first *PNG*, then these areas become black.

**The code:**

```
<?php

function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){ 
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct); 
}

$image1 = imagecreatefrompng('a.png'); //300 x 300
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('b.png'); //150 x 150

$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
imagealphablending($merged_image, false);
imagesavealpha($merged_image, true);

imagecopy($merged_image, $image1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300);
imagecopymerge_alpha($merged_image, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, 50);

header('Content-Type: ' . image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_PNG));
imagepng($merged_image);

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you have tried?

Comment: Does it seem that there is no workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

How about if you try this instead?  It works for me.

```
<?php

$image1 = imagecreatefrompng('a.png'); //300 x 300
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('b.png'); //150 x 150
$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);

// DEFINE MAGENTA AS THE TRANSPARENCY COLOR AND FILL THE IMAGE FIRST
$transparentColor = imagecolorallocate($merged_image, 255, 0, 255); 
imagecolortransparent($merged_image, $transparentColor);
imagefill($merged_image, 0, 0, $transparentColor);

imagesavealpha($merged_image, true);

imagealphablending($image1, false);
imagecopyresampled($merged_image, $image1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300, 300, 300);
imagealphablending($image1, true);
imagedestroy($image1); // FREE UP SOME MEMORY

imagealphablending($image2, false);
imagecopyresampled($merged_image, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300, 150, 150);
imagealphablending($image2, true);
imagedestroy($image2); // FREE UP SOME MEMORY

imagealphablending($merged_image, false);
imagesavealpha($merged_image, true);

header('Content-Type: ' . image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_PNG));
imagepng($merged_image);

?>
```

It took me a lot of experimenting in this.  I hope this helps you or someone else who may stumble upon this.

Comment: It appears that before adding a transparent image, you should set the imagealphablending to false prior to copying the source image to the destination image and then set it to true after you have copied it.  I don't know why this works but it does.